# How to escape keyword ''pos' from xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using <fo:basic-link> tag  to add an hyperlink in my .xsl file .The destination URL contain 'pos' which is a keywod in xsl .How to escape this character  from xsl compilations.
**Below is my code :**

<fo:block >Link To  Module :<fo:basic-link
color="blue" external-destination="https://www.add.com/aass/sss/module=CAR&**pos=11.1**">https://www.add.com/aass/sss/module=CAR&**pos=11.1**</fo:basic-link></fo:block>

```
ERROR:The reference to entity "pos" must end with the ';' 
 delimiter.
```

Comment: Instead of `&pos=` try `&amp;pos=`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `pos` that's reserved, it's `&`. And it's not XSLT that reserves it, it's XML. In any XML document (including an XSLT stylesheet) ampersand needs to be written as `&amp;`.

Also note, it's not universally supported, but in many cases the `&` between query parameters in a URL can be replaced by `;`.